# Rename column for all tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to rename column for all tables in my databse.
I could get list of columns using this query:

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME= <Column Name>;
```

But how actually I could rename it as simple as possible and do not write

```
ALTER TABLE <Table Name >RENAME COLUMN <Old name> to <New Name>;
```

for each table.

I've tried to write a procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  renameColumn $$
     CREATE PROCEDURE renameColumn(IN oldName tinytext, IN newName tinytext)
     BEGIN
       DECLARE @name VARCHAR(255);
       DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         
       DECLARE tableName_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME=oldName;
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
       OPEN tableName_cursor;
       rename_loop: LOOP
        FETCH  tableName_cursor @name;
        ALTER TABLE @name RENAME COLUMN oldName to newName;
         IF exit_loop THEN
             LEAVE rename_loop;
         END IF;
       END LOOP rename_loop;
     END $$
     DELIMITER;
```

But I have the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;

DECLARE ta' at line 3

Could you please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Perhaps export the schema. Find/replace the column name. Import the schema.

Comment: see [stored-procedure-to-add-remove-prefix-by-rename-table-mysql](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/stored-procedure-to-add-remove-prefix-by-rename-table-mysql) for a similar dynamic renaming example

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME,
    ' RENAME COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME,
    ' NEW_', COLUMN_NAME,
    ';') AS rename_script 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution hope it will help

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME= 'OldColumn';

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      set @name = @name + '.OldColumn'
      EXEC sp_rename  @name, 'NewColumn', 'COLUMN';
      print(@name)
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```